# Jump straight to passcode when finger isn't recognized but Touch ID?

Tags: iphone, touch-id

When I'm sweaty (e.g. jogging), I find it very difficult to unlock my iPhone 7 with touch ID. I use my fingerprint-registered finger with the home button, but I get stuck in a loop of it forever saying "Try Again", rather than it giving up and letting me use my passcode instead.

Using a different (not registered) finger doesn't seem to make a difference. Likewise, giving only a very brief press of the home button doesn't reliably open the screen to enter passcode, though that *does* work when I'm not sweaty.

This can be a bit frustrating, as after a run I can spend a full minute stabbing at the home button to try and unlock the phone and tell Strava I'm no longer running. I accept that touch ID probably isn't going to reliably work when my fingers are sweaty, but is there a way I can more reliably jump straight to passcode entry?

Answer (score 2):

1. Rest your finger on Touch ID.
2. It says ‘try again’, don’t lift your finger.
3. Depress and release the button.
4. The passcode screen will appear immediately.